# Synonymize [circular-buffer] ← [ring-buffer]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The tag wiki for [circular-buffer](/questions/tagged/circular-buffer) states:

> A circular buffer, cyclic buffer or ring buffer is a data structure that uses a single, fixed-size buffer as if it were connected end-to-end.

The tag wiki for [ring-buffer](/questions/tagged/ring-buffer) states:

> A ring buffer is a data structure in which elements are stored in a circular ring.

These seem to refer to the same concept, so I suggest that [ring-buffer](/questions/tagged/ring-buffer) be merged into [circular-buffer](/questions/tagged/circular-buffer).

Comment: I'd offer a concurrent proposal that [tag:circular-buffer] be merged into [tag:ring-buffer]. Wouldn't want users to get to one end of the tag chain and have nowhere to go...